# Visual Basic: Iterate a folder's files

Tags: vb.net, file-io, recursion

I would like to iterate the files in a folder in Visual Basic.
I want to check for each file's name. I heard about a Dir function or something, but I am not very sure how to use it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Imports System.IO

Dim fInfo As FileInfo()                
Dim i As Integer = 0         
Dim path AS String = "INSERT FILE PATH"       
Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(path)   

fInfo = dInfo.GetFiles("*.txt")              
Dim files As String()                
Dim File As String                
files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")                
For Each File In files                        
   'Do Something With The File                 
   i += 1                
Next
```

Comment: FileInfo() and DirectoryInfo send errors saying they are undefined. And Directory says it is not declared =/

Comment: Sorry, I meant Visual Basic .NET?

Comment: Yes, Imports System.IO and I forgot the 'New' on the DirectoryInfo object.  I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Almost there! Look, inside the loop, I use File.ToString and I get the whole path. How do I do to just get the file name itself?

Comment: I believe you can use Path.GetFileName(File.ToString)

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm!